# French for “wasted” as in “get wasted”?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

What is the usual French way for saying 'wasted'? When drinking in a bar, in order to say like belows for example? English is not my first language but I think 'wasted' is a familiar language. Thanks for any input. 
"I never get wasted but Patrick was in his usual wasted self".

Answer (score 8):

Let me try to list some synonyms for getting wasted/getting drunk :

- **Boire plus que de raison** (formal,sometimes used as an euphemism depending on how drunk you were really)
- **Se saouler** (less formal)
- **Prendre/se mettre une cuite** (less formal)
- **Prendre/se mettre une guinze** (in Belgium)
- **Prendre/se mettre une murge** (very familiar, rather young. "Se mettre" implies somehow a will to do it, while "prendre" is rather used when you didn't really plan it)
- **Prendre une biture**
- **S'en mettre/prendre une belle** (e.g: "Je m'en suis mis une belle samedi soir !") Here the actual noun - was it murge, cuite, guinze or whatever) is deduced

On the "result" of getting wasted, expressing "being drunk":

- **Être ivre**,**Être saoul** (quite neutral, nor too formal nor too familiar) Note: While "Se Saouler" exists, there no such thing as "S'ivresser"
- **Être en état d'ébriété** (rather formal/official)
- **Être bourré** (informal)
- **Être beurré**
- **Être torché**
- **Avoir un coup dans le nez** (when you drank too much but are not totally wasted)
- **Être pompette** (old - there also not totally wasted. Note there's a French canadian show named "[Les recettes pompette](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Recettes_Pompettes_(France))" where host and guest drink alcohol while cooking)

And some more colourful expressions :

- [Être saoul comme la bourrique de Robespierre](https://www.france-pittoresque.com/spip.php?article7648)
- Être plein comme une barrique
- Être rond comme une queue de pelle (or other things, see [this page](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/etre-rond-comme.php) for more "round" things and an explanation of why "rond" = "ivre")
- Être saoul comme un polonais/comme toute la Pologne ([reference](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/saoul_comme_un_Polonais))

These are the first ones popping to my mind and this is hardly an exhaustive list. There are many expressions conveying the same meaning and new ones are yet to be created. Note that I'm almost 40 years old, there may be a whole new set of expressions used by younger people nowadays...

For the sake of it, I will also add these 2 links I found looking further for some expressions, but most of the ones that are not mentionned in this answer or other answers I almost never used/heard myself:

[Link 1](http://www.topito.com/top-expressions-saoul-bourre-dechiray) & 
[Link 2](http://www.topito.com/top-expressions-argot-cuite-boire-bourrer-la-gueule-pinter-la-ruchasse)

Comment: Bien vu! J'étais en train d'écrire une réponse au moment où celle-ci a été postée. Selon moi, _torché_ serait le sens le plus proche du _wasted_ anglais, qu'en pensez-vous?

Comment: Je mettrais être torché, être bourré et être beurré dans le même sac pour "to be wasted". Très honnêtement je ne vois aucune différence de registre ou de degré d'imbibation entre ces 3 mots. Peut-être "beurré" est-il un peu plus 80's et moins utilisé de nos jours...

Comment: Impressionnant! Merci pour cette liste. Si on ajoutait en plus les comparatifs (bourré comme un coing, beurré comme une biscotte, saoul comme un polak, rond comme une queue de pelle...) il y aurait certainement matière à une véritable encyclopédie.

Comment: Je m'en voudrai certainement de ne pas y apporter ma pierre avec, je crois, une des plus rares que je connaisse : *saoul comme la barrique de Robespierre* dont on trouvera la raison ici :  https://www.france-pittoresque.com/spip.php?article7648

Comment: @aCOSwt > Je vais la rajouter avec d'autres qui me sont venues entretemps, mais cela dit c'est bien la "bourrique" de Robespierre (son âne), pas la barrique.

Comment: @Laurent S. My bad! C'est toi qui a raison! Bonne santé!

Comment: C'est selon moi la réponse la plus étoffée. Il manque encore quelques expressions, comme _se mettre une race_ ou alors _se mettre minable_ ou encore _boire comme un trou_. Par contre, je ne mettrais pas _être bourré(e)_ et _être torché(e)_ dans le même registre, l'un étant plus familier que l'autre selon moi.

Comment: @Kii J'avoue avoir hésité, pour cette réponse comme d'autres sous forme de liste, à compléter mon post avec les réponses données par d'autres. Surtout dans la mesure où quoi que je fasse, je ne serai jamais exhaustif.  Quant à "bourré" et "torché", j'ai du mal à penser à une situation où j'emploierais volontiers l'un et surtout pas l'autre... Pour moi c'est soit saoul ou ivre dans un registre plus formel, soit n'importe lequel des autres pour un registre plus détendu...

Comment: je met un joli +1 juste pour référence aux recettes pompettes :D

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let's talk about a litteral translation. *Getting wasted* means something like *se gaspiller*.

In an alcoholic context, someone *getting wasted* is someone drinking too much alcohol and someone *wasted* is someone *very drunk*.

I think the most common word to describe someone drunk is indeed, as pointed out by other answers, is *être bourré* but I feel like *bourré* does not convey the meaning of someone really, really drunk.

Another word I can think of, which convey a stronger meaning of drunkness, would be ***être torché*** (but may be a bit less used today).

Here's a list :

- *Être ivre* is neutral and formal way of *Being drunk*
- *Être saoûl* is also a neutral and formal way of saying it
- *Être bourré* is less formal to say *Being drunk*
- *Être torché* is familiar and has stronger meaning
- *Être plein* or *Être rond* are also used sometimes
- *Être défoncé* is more used for other drugs but also works for alcohol

Other expressions linked to alcohol :

- *Picoler* is a familiar verb meaning *To drink alcohol*
- *Prendre une cuite* is familiar, meaning *To drink alcohol until being sick*
- *Se mettre minable*
- *Se mettre une race* / *Se prendre une race*
- *Boire comme un trou*

Answer (score 3):

To keep a familiar language, you can say:
`Se la coller` ou `Se la mettre` ou `Se dechirer la gueule` ou `se mettre cher`

> EN: I never get wasted but Patrick was in his usual wasted self
>
> FR: Je me la colle pas, mais Patrick a l'habitude de se la coller

Answer (score 2):

Au bar, familièrement, on dira *bourré(e)* : *"Je ne suis jamais bourré(e)"* - *"Je ne me bourre jamais la gueule"*

Ou encore *pinté(e)* : *"Je ne suis jamais pinté(e)"* - *"Je ne me pinte jamais"*

Moins vulgairement on dirait *saoul(e)* : *"Je ne suis jamais saoul(e)*" - *"Je ne me saoule jamais"*

Au bar hein! Parce que... dans d'autres contextes... *get wasted* a d'autres significations.

EDIT (suggéré par le commentaire ci-contre de Laurent S) :

- *Pinter*, au sens général de boire est attesté dès le XIIIe siècle.
- Il évolue vers le sens de *boire beaucoup* aux débuts du XVIe, spécialement en parlant d'un ivrogne.
- Dans le même temps apparait la forme pronominale (*se pinter*)
- L'adjectif *pinté* qui correspond à *être saoul* est d'invention plus récente (milieu du XXe)

Source DHLF.

Comme avec tous les mots ayant évolué au XXe siècle, il est donc parfaitement possible que certains auteurs voire les locuteurs de certaines régions de la francophonie aient conservé l'usage précédent de boire beaucoup.

D'ailleurs il est bien connu que l'on peut boire beaucoup sans nécessairement être saoul. Hein ?
HIPS!
Pardon! ;)

Comment: Il serait intéressant de préciser l'origine. En Belgique, pinter c'est surtout boire des bières (des pintes) sans forcément se saouler.

Comment: @LaurentS. ceci dit, vu le degré d'alcoolémie dans les bières belges, boire _des_ pintes implique la plupart du temps de se saouler :P

Comment: @Kii ca dépend des bières, mais effectivement pour certaines, ca cogne dur :-)

Answer (score 1):

In that situation, I'd probably say something like:

> Je ne prends jamais de **cuite** alors que Patrick... il était là, **bourré**, comme d’habitude.

Unlike "wasted", « cuite » is a noun, though.

Comment: Je crois que le pronom *il* est bien inutile. => *Alors que Patrick était là*. Si tu veux insister sur le contraste du locuteur avec Patrick alors, à la rigueur, tu peux le reprendre mais alors avec *lui* : * alors que Patrick, lui, était là, bourré...*

Comment: @aCOSwt Hi. Je m'en serais aussi bien passé, certes, mais est-ce qu'il ne suffirait pas de mettre ces trois petits points pour le rendre grammaticalement correct ? :)

Comment: Oh wait! Je n'ai pas dit qu'il était grammaticalement incorrect. Une virgule, des points de suspension et, roule ma poule, on peut commencer une nouvelle proposition avec un sujet. J'ai juste dit qu'il était inutile. C'est encore à dire qu'il alourdit sensiblement la phrase. Mais... tu me diras... quand on est bourré... ! ;)